# Pyinstaller EXE: FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory 'C:\\Users\\my.name\\Desktop\\EPE 2.0\\dist\\main\\timezonefinder\\timezone_names.json'

Tags: python, json, anaconda, exe, pyinstaller

When I try to run my exe created by pyinstaller (newest development version, python v3.6 in an anaconda environment) I get the following error:

```
File "site-packages\timezonefinder\timezonefinder.py", line 27, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\simon.rhee\\Desktop\\EPE 
2.0\\dist\\main\\timezonefinder\\timezone_names.json'
[8984] Failed to execute script main
```

Thank you for your help, please let me know if I can provide more information which will make helping me out easier or more informative for those that may have the same question.

Comment: You should provide some code. I would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug with the conda-forge version of pyinstaller, updating to the development version will help with other problems and manually copying the timezonefinder folder from the virtual enviroment to the dist folder will fix this issue.